# How can the onHover text on tableHead can be edited material-ui

Tags: sorting, material-ui

I searched a prop in the tableHead component of material-ui but i can't figure out how to edit the onHover text, when I hover my header in my table it displays 'sort' i want to traduct but can't find a way to have access to this text.

```
const EnhancedTableHead = (props) => {
  const { onSelectAllClick, order, orderBy, numSelected, rowCount, onRequestSort } = props;
  const createSortHandler = property => event => {
    onRequestSort(event, property);
  };

  return (
    <TableHead>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell padding="checkbox">
          <Checkbox
            indeterminate={numSelected > 0 && numSelected < rowCount}
            checked={numSelected === rowCount}
            onChange={onSelectAllClick}
          />
        </TableCell>
        {rows.map(
          row => (
            <TableCell
              key={row.id}
              numeric={row.numeric}
              padding={row.disablePadding ? 'none' : 'default'}
              sortDirection={orderBy === row.id ? order : false}
            >
              <Tooltip
                title="Sort"
                placement={row.numeric ? 'bottom-end' : 'bottom-start'}
                enterDelay={300}
              >
                <TableSortLabel
                  active={orderBy === row.id}
                  direction={order}
                  onClick={createSortHandler(row.id)}
                >
                  {row.label}
                </TableSortLabel>
              </Tooltip>
            </TableCell>
          ),
          this,
        )}
      </TableRow>
    </TableHead>
  );
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it,

It was a simple Tooltip lol,

```
<Tooltip
  title="Sort" // had to edit this one, 
  placement={row.numeric ? 'bottom-end' : 'bottom-start'}
  enterDelay={300}
>
```